# Unable to get defined component on page edit in Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I have just started to use Magnolia CMS for the development of my web application. I am using the tutorials provided on the documentation page of MAGNOLIA Website. I've created the page templates and areas. But on going through the development of components, i am facing a problem. After the creation of the components, it is getting on the component list at the time when I edit the page.

Comment: can you provide more information?  This really doesnt explain what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your problem is getting newly created component on the list of available components in the area for user to choose from. Correct?

To do so, you need to add your component on the list of available components in the area configuration. This allows you to make different components available in different areas. For details on where to find given area configuration, please see  [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/Creating+an+area#Creatinganarea-Makingcomponentsavailableinthearea).

HTH,
Jan